# Implement strcmp function in C

Tags: c

I want to Implement `strcmp` so this is what i have try:

```
int compare(char *str1, char *str2, int maximumCharactersToCompare)
{
    int i;
    int result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < maximumCharactersToCompare; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] > str2[i])
            result = 1;
        else if (str1[i] < str2[i])
            result = -1;
        if (str1[i] == '\0' || str1[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

My usage:

```
char str1[127];
char str2[127];

printf("Please enter first string: ");
scanf("%s", str1);

printf("Please enter second string: ");
scanf("%s", str2);

int result = compare(str1, str2, 127);
```

So my problem is that if i try to compare `"test"` and `"test "` this return `0` and i can see that `str2` is equat to `"test"` instead of `"test "` and thats why my result is `0`

Comment: test lengths first. If they don't match, then return "not equal". Once you have equal lengths, then you can safely compare.

Comment: But why my both str1 and str2 get the value "test" although i typed str2="test "

Comment: That is beacuse the `scanf` stops at the first whitespace.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there is no reason to test any lengths. The terminating `\0` of the shorter string will be *inequal* to the character in the longer string.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that's true. Why recoding strcmp? (well I recoded it in assembly, but I didn't have access to any C library)

Answer (score 0):

you type

```
if (str1[i] == '\0' || str1[i] == '\0')
```

try

```
if (str1[i] == '\0' || str2[i] == '\0')
```